# Object detection without bounding boxes

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection

I'm trying to think of an architecture to perform object detection from labelled images (according to object class) but any information in the labels with respect to object location. I thought I could setup a sliding window and a CNN, but I'm wondering how to train this model as the sliding window won't find the object most of the times. Is there any type of loss function that can handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.di.ens.fr/~josef/publications/Oquab15.pdf